# change pgsql port

Tags: postgresql

I have currently an installed pgsql instance that is running on port `1486`. I want to change this port to `5433`, how should I proceed for this?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

There should be a line in your `postgresql.conf` file that says:

```
port = 1486
```

Change that.

The location of the file can vary depending on your install options. On Debian-based distros it is `/etc/postgresql/8.3/main/`

On Windows it is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\data`

Don't forget to `sudo service postgresql restart` for changes to take effect.

Comment: On Ubuntu (and possibly other Linuxes), you can use `locate postgresql.conf` to find the path(s) of this file.

Comment: depending on the version you have installed on ubuntu type `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/x.x/main/postgresql.conf` you will find an entry `PORT = ...` change that  with the one you want and save after that restart the server using `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: Where is the postgresql.conf? could you post the full path?

Comment: @Sören, postgresql.conf location depends on individual installation. If you know where your Postgres has installed its data (your database's physical files), you can find it inside that folder. Some Unix distros have `locate` utility that let's you find any archive (I know Ubuntu and CentOs have this utility). I have seen this file inside `/home/postgresql`, `/var/lib/pgsql/data`... inspect the script that's used to run `initdb` and look for `PGDATA` variable.

Comment: If you are trying to launch psql you may run into problems since psql still defaults to `5432`. You may want to do `psql --port 1486`

Comment: You will probably need to open the conf file with `sudo` as well. Run `ls -la` to check if you have writing permission.

Answer (score 47):

You can also change the port when starting up:

```
$ pg_ctl -o "-F -p 5433" start
```

Or

```
$ postgres -p 5433
```

More about this in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/reference-server.html).

Comment: Why `-F`? Has it something with specifying port?

Comment: looks outdated to me

Comment: -F is for sync off when doing rapid testing it helps a lot.

Comment: As @söze mentioned above, if you use `psql` after this, make sure to set `psql --port 1486`.