# can i install multiple versions of same db in my localhost?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql  . My prod database version is 8.4 .
 My local database version is 9.1

is there any way i can use multiple version of same db and switch for testing?

because some work in 9.x not work on 8.x !!

just curious question!!

Comment: Probably, but you are setting yourself up for writing code that won't work in production.  I've never done it myself, but one of my former co-workers has.

Comment: Little details like your OS and version, how you installed PostgreSQL, etc tend to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, Just make them listen to two different ports

[I want to change pgsql port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187438/want-to-change-pgsql-port)

for more info.

8.4 and 9.1 should come with seperate config files

Comment: i hope fedora will not say postgres is already installed . if i gave exact package name

Comment: I would suggest running one from /usr/local if possible

Comment: I (strongly) suggest building one (or perhaps both) from source using the `--prefix` flag to `configure` to keep them separate. Any reasonable development environment will have the necessary build tools.