# Changing postgresql server port from ansible playbook

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I have a requirement to use custom port for postgresql server. Documentations says to do it this way but it does not work:

```
- name: Set listening port
  become_user: root
  postgresql_set: name=port
                  value='{{ db_port }}'
```

It gives me error:

```
TASK [createdb : Set listening port] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ansible.vallsoft.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user \"postgres\"\n"}
```

If I try to become user 'postgres' instead of 'root', it gives error:

```
TASK [createdb : Set listening port] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ansible.vallsoft.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to get port value due to : must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command\n"}
```

**Edit**:
I install posgresql server also from ansible this way:

```
- name: Install PostgreSQL
  apt:
    name: ['postgresql', 'postgresql-contrib', 'libpq-dev', 'python-psycopg2', 'python3-pip']
  tags: packages
```

Comment: Before you can have Ansible (or anything else) use the port you have to configure PG to listen on that port: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187438/change-pgsql-port

Comment: Yes, but my intention is to configure listening port automatically (not manually). Ansible supposed to allow this using command 'postgresql_set', but it does not work.. Or am I mistaken and the purpose of this command is different?

Comment: Is there any chance the PG installation has a different superuser?

Comment: Can Ansible modify files directly?

Comment: @Don R do you mean that default user is postgres? It is fresh installation so I guess it should be, I edited my question, added info as to how I install it

Comment: It does look like it would create the default Postgres user as the superuser. Does Ansible pass credentials in some way? Did it ask you for a password for that DB login?

Comment: @Don R no it does not ask for password. Forgot to mention that I run playbook from sudo, if I correct, then no password is needed to become postgres from root.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the postgres operating system user, which is the system account the DBMS runs as, and the postgres database user, which is the default superuser login in the DBMS. You normally don't want the O/S user to have a password because you don't want anyone or anything to log in to the O/S as that user, but you do need to log in to PostgreSQL as postgres in order to issue ALTER SYSTEM. Is there a specific reason you need to change the listening port using Ansible?

Comment: I need because applications that will be deployed, require to connect to multiple postgres servers, it is weird I know..

Answer (score 0):

Uh, sorry, it seem that it was my fault.
I checked postgresql users table

```
select * from pg_user;
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | userepl | usebypassrls |  passwd  | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+---------+--------------+----------+----------+-----------
 postgres |       10 | f           | f        | t       | t            | ******** |          | 
(1 row)
```

And seems that somehow single superuser posgres become regular user and the installation has no superusers whatsoever..

I'm nor sure how it happened, maybe some other scripts I tested, did this.

I reinstalled everything and now all works as intended..